# d3 hierarchy in typescript throws error for value on .sum?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

i'm trying to follow a tutorial with this code:

```
var data = {
  name: "A1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "B1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "C1",
          value: 100,
        },
        {
          name: "C2",
          value: 300,
        },
        {
          name: "C3",
          value: 200,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "B2",
      value: 200,
    },
  ],
};
var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum((d) => d.value);
```

but i get this warning:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ name: string; children: ({
> name: string; children: { name: string; value: number; }[]; value?:
> undefined; } | { name: string; value: number; children?: undefined;
> })[]; }'

why is it not working?
this is the full code:

```
var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
 

/* PACK LAYOUT */

    var packLayout = d3.pack();
    packLayout.size([400, 200]);
    packLayout.padding(10);
    
    root.sum((d) => d.value);
    packLayout(root);
    
    var packNodes = d3
      .select("#pack g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")")
      .call(handleEvents);
    packNodes
      .append("circle")
      .classed("the-node", true)
      .attr("r", (d) => d.r)
      .style("fill", "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)")
      .style("stroke", "#2f2f2f");
    
    packNodes
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("dy", 4)
      .attr("dx", 0)
      .text((d) => (d.children === undefined ? d.data.name : ""));
```

but i am having a hard time since i find it hard finding resources with typescript

Comment: Try `const root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum((d) => d.value || 0);`. Does it help?

Comment: d3.hierarchy is changing the structure of your data internally,  [as per the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy) this allows you to pass the result of d3.group or d3.rollup to d3.hierarchy.

So the inferred type of the datum coming into your sum is incorrect.

I think the fix would be to convert the output of d3.group to the data structure d3.hierarchy is expecting. That way the type would get inferred correctly. But not sure, I'm using `.sum((d: any) => d.value)` to get around it.